# Third tube puncture in 3 weeks

Tags: innertube, puncture

I have the 3-rd puncture of the rear wheel tube during 3 weeks. All of them have the same pattern: 1 small breach about 0.5mm long. I added the photographs of the last one.

Bubble inside the water coming out of the tube through the puncture.
[image]

The little puncture.
[image]

Previous patched puncture
[image]

After the second puncture I thought, that it was caused by a grain of sand that got between the tube and the tire. So when I assembled the wheel I carefully cleaned the space between the tube and the tire with open hand.

Now I have no idea what can cause these punctures and what should I do to avoid them?

Comment: It seems like you're using the word "camera" where "tube" should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it! After careful inspection of the tire I found a small piece of glass stuck into it:

[image: Small piece of glass with a ruler]

It's sharp side was facing the tube.

Here is the place where it was stuck:

[image]

On the internal side of the tire you can see a little hole:

[image]

It was hard to feel this little thing by hand. But when I pumped the tire and rode, creating high pressure, this sharp edge has eventually punctured the tube.

Comment: It helps if you carefully remove the tube and mark it and the tire somehow so that you know what it's position was relative to the tire and the rim.  Then, when you find the leak, you only need check a small area of the tire and rim.

Comment: The reason you should mount the tyre in a way that the lettering on the side-wall sits at the valve-hole. This way makes it easier to locate a foreign body in the tyre.